# URDF from a working ROS package not shown

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm creating a Gazebo package for a URDF-based, dual-arm robot. Its ROS package has been working for years. Robot model doesn't appear on Gazebo, wireframe or collision either. What should I check?

[URDF](https://github.com/130s/rtmros_nextage/blob/indigo/add/gz/nextage_description/urdf/NextageOpen.urdf) (it's URDF but in the [launch file](https://github.com/130s/rtmros_nextage/blob/indigo/add/gz/nextage_gazebo/launch/nextage_world.launch) I use this as a `xacro`).
The entire Gazebo package can be seen [in this pull request](https://github.com/130s/rtmros_nextage/pull/5/files).

Saw [a similar thread](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6944/urdf-joints-not-appearing-in-gazebo/) but most of the joints in my model aren't fixed.

Also, this 'invisible' robot keeps falling (so I'm trying to [add contact parameters](https://github.com/130s/rtmros_nextage/commit/985953e69f8a5b62b7dce7c723fc8e5f4304b263#diff-fdc508593a8046af59bf946fdccfab01R6)), but this is another problem.

Gazebo 2.2.6, ROS Indigo
Thank you.

---

Update) Adding environment variables trick to package.xml` in the package that contains models didn't work unfortunately.

Meanwhile, I don't see either the list of links in the model pane. I only see `__default__`, string of which doesn't exist anywhere in my packages. [image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12070/urdf-from-a-working-ros-package-not-shown/) by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-11-23**:
This looks similar to the problems I encountered here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7178/mesh-geometries-using-xacro-not-working-with-drcsimgazebo4-working-previously-with-drcsimgazebo2/ and here: https://bitbucket.org/ihmcrobotics/ihmc_ros/issues/52/atlas-controller-fails-to-work-properly.

You could test if it's the same resource loading issue by adding primitive based geometry. That worked in my cases (but didn't help with the meshes obviously).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I figured it out. As noted in "Inertial Element" section in the [URDF in Gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf) (sorry linking didn't work, maybe with brackets in the URL?), mass must be greater than zero for any link to not be ignored. In my case there were a few link in the upstream nodes whose mass was 0.

Good standalone debugging tool `gzsdf` (for Gazebo2) was also mentioned in [this chapter](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf#VerifyingtheGazeboModelWorks).

---

Originally posted by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) with karma: 91 on 2016-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Addition:

you might need something like this in your package xml to ensure that gazebo finds model path

> ```
> <export>
>      <gazebo_ros plugin_path="${prefix}/lib"
> >                 gazebo_media_path="${prefix}/.."      
>             gazebo_resource_path="${prefix}/..:${prefix}/resource"
>             gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/.."/>
> </export>
> ```

I once had some problems with missing intertias for link that caused some problems.
One last thing that might be missing are transmissions.

I don't have the time to look at the complete URDF so all of this are just guesses

Old answer:

Your launch file has `-sdf` instead of `-urdf` in the arguments.
Please let me know if this does not solve your problem...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on 2015-11-19**:
Thanks for taking a look. No changing to `-urdf` didn't work (although it sounds the right thing to do. I've updated the link in my OP).

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2015-11-20**:
updated the answer, I am not sure if you have been notified...

**Comment by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on 2015-11-20**:
@evilBiber thx again, for some reason email notification stopped for me. Anyways I've updated my OP.